# MarkLogic converters upgrade

Tags: marklogic-9

I'm doing an upgrade from MarkLogic 9.x to 10.x on both stand alone MarkLogic servers and a MarkLogic cluster, all on Linux.

We will need to go up to the new 10.x converters, this link ( below ) describes the installation of the converters  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/procedures#id_28962  ,  but I need to know if there is any configuration of the converters that needs to be done after installation, or will it just pick up the previous configuration of the 9.x converters? It looks like no config is needed but need to double check, especially as we have a cluster.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special configuration of the converters, but you should install the version of the converters package that matches the version of MarkLogic Server.

So, if you are installing MarkLogic 10, uninstall the 9.x converters and then install the 10.x converters on each host.